# prolog is tree balanced

Tags: tree, prolog

I need to implement a predicate `isBalanced/1` such that `isBalanced(T)` is true if `T` is a tree that is balanced.

A binary tree is in this case, defined by the structure node(left,right), where left and right can be either another node or any Prolog data item.

What I have so far:

```
height(node(L,R), Size) :-
    height(L, Left_Size),
    height(R, Right_Size),
    Size is Left_Size + Right_Size + 1 .
height(l(_),1).

isBalanced(l(_)).
isBalanced(node(B1,B2)):-
    height(B1,H1),
    height(B2,H2),
    abs(H1-H2) =< 1,
    isBalanced(B1),
    isBalanced(B2).
```

Expected output:

```
?- isBalanced(1).
true.
?- isBalanced(node(1,2)).
true.
?- isBalanced(node(1,node(1,node(1,2)))).
false.
```

It does not work, any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ... and add l/1 back! Instead, remove this incorrect cut.

Comment: In your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30636790/772868), you had `size(empty, Size).` But now you say `height(_,1)`. Do you mean by that thateverything is of height one? You  rather mean only `height(l(_),1`)`.

Comment: Also note that `height` assumes a tree with `node/2` terms, whereas `isBalanced/1` assumes a tree with `b/1` terms. They are incompatible, so your queries will either fail or loop (provided `height(_,1)` has been corrected).

Comment: A binary tree is balanced if, at every node, the difference between the number of leaves appearing in the left and right subtree is at most one. (A tree which contains just one leaf is considered balanced.)

Comment: Right! But nevertheless `b/2` and `node/2` just don't unify!

Comment: replace `b(` by `node(` ; and add `l(_)` to the fact of `height/2`.

Answer (score 3):

How are you *representing* your tree? It looks to me that

- `l(_)` represents the empty tree, and
- `node(L,R)` represents a non-empty tree.

And I suspect that your `height/2` has a bug in that you seem to have defined the height of an empty tree as being 1 (rather than 0).

I would probably represent a binary tree as follows:

- `nil` — the empty tree
- `tree(D,L,R)` — a non-empty tree, where

  - `D`: payload data
  - `L`: left subtree
  - `R`: right subtree

so that one might represent the tree

```
    a
   / \
  b   c   
 /   / \
d   e   f
```

as

```
tree( a ,
  tree( b ,
    tree( d , nil , nil ) ,
    nil
  ) ,
  tree( c ,
    tree( e , nil , nil ) ,
    tree( f , nil , nil ) 
) .
```

and a leaf node (a tree with no subtrees) looks something like

```
tree( data , nil , nil )
```

**Determination of *Balance***

So, working from that representation, and from the definition

> A binary tree is balanced if:
>
> - Its left sub-tree is balanced
> - Its right sub-tree is balanced
> - The respective heights of the sub-trees differ by no more than 1

We can easily write a descriptive solution to the problem:

```
is_balanced( nil         ) .  % the empty tree is balanced
is_balanced( tree(_,L,R) ) :- % a non-empty tree is balanced IF ...
  is_balanced(L) ,            % - the left sub-tree is balanced
  is_balanced(R) ,            % - the right sub-tree is balanced
  tree_height(L,LH) ,         % - the height of the left sub-tree
  tree_height(R,RH) ,         % - the height of the right sub-tree
  abs( LH - RH ) < 2          % - differ by no more than 1
  .                           % Right?
```

We just need to compute the height of a tree.

**Computation of Height**

One can compute the height of such a tree as follows:

```
tree_height( nil         , 0 ) .  % the depth of an empty tree is zero.
tree_height( tree(_,L,R) , H ) :- % for a non-empty tree...
  tree_height( L , LH ) ,         % - we compute the height of the left subtree
  tree_height( R , RH ) ,         % - we compute the height of the right subtree
  H is 1 + max( LH , RH )         % - the overall height is 1 more than the higher of the two values thus obtained.
  .                               % Right?
```

**Efficiency**

One might note that there

- seems to be a lot of tree traversals happening, and
- `is_balanced/2` has a *suspicious resemblance* to `tree_height/2`.

Therefore, one might optimize things by blending the two and computing depth on the fly:

**Edited:** Added wrapper predicate `is_balanced/1`:

```
is_balanced( T ) :- is_balanced( T, _ ) .

is_balanced( nil         , 0 ) .   % the empty tree is balanced and has a height of zero.
is_balanced( tree(_,L,R) , H ) :-  % a non-empty tree is balanced IF ...
  is_balanced( L , LH ) ,          % - its left subtree is balanced, and
  is_balanced( R , RH ) ,          % - its right subtree is balanced, and 
  abs( LH - RH) < 2 ,              % - their respective heights differ by no more than 1, and
  H is 1 + max( LH , RH )          % - the current tree's height is 1 more than the larger of the heights of the two subtrees.
  .                                % Easy! (And elegant!)
```

Comment: Thanks, I especially like the optimized version. However, what I need is a predicate that takes just one input, also note that neither of your answers return true for `isBalanced(1).`, which is the requirement for my task.

Comment: Where or how do I include the predicate max()

Comment: You shouldn't need to include anything: [`max/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?function=max/2) is a built-in ISO arithmetic function. You should be able to say `X is max(3*2,4*5).` and get back `X = 20`. But something like `( X > Y -> Z = X ; Z = Y )` should unify Z with the larger of `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Also, see my amended answer that includes a wrapper predicate `is_balanced/1`.

Comment: I still get the wrong answer from your solution. It asks if I want to `Correct to: "is_balanced(1)"?`, if I select yes, it returns false, which is not the answer I need it to be true. If I select no, is really spits the dummy and causes an exception!

`1 ?- isBalanced(1).
Correct to: "is_balanced(1)"? yes
false.

2 ?- isBalanced(1).
Correct to: "is_balanced(1)"? no
ERROR: residue_vars/2: Undefined procedure: isBalanced/1
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         is_balanced/1
ERROR:         is_balanced/2
   Exception: (7) isBalanced(1) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
3 ?- `